# React: order of execution

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to react and was following this example

https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/QKzAgB?editors=0010

Now, to my understanding, the following should be Order of execution

- Execution start from LoginControl
- Then comes constructor
- Then it goes to render method and runs

  `button = <LoginButton onClick={this.handleLoginClick}/>};`

Now the control should go to `LoginButton` function but when I debug control goes to `Greetings` then `UserGreetings` and then to `LoginButton`. Why is that?
Also, within `LoginButton` we have `<button onClick={props.onClick}>`, what `props.onClick` do? What does it call?

If someone could explain it that would be much appreciated. I have already read many articles and spent some hours on debugging but couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sara,
I am going to start with the latter question.

`LoginButton` is a component and all it does and has is a button which on the onClick event triggers a method called `props.onClick`. Then what is `props.onClick`? It is some method which is passed from the parent component to this component.

Going back to the code, let's search for the parent component, which in this case is going to be the top-level component `LoginFlow`. If `isLoggedIn` is false it assigns to button `<LoginButton onClick={this.handleLoginClick} />;`. Do you see the `onClick` prop? That is what gets passed as the `props.onClick` to the `LoginButton`, therefore the function that gets executed on click is the `handleLoginClick` of the `LoginFlow`.

As for the former question, it is just what the `LoginFlow` component returns. Look at the return statement part of the component - it returns `Greetings` with the `isLoggedIn` prop, which in turn (being `true` in this case) goes to the `userGreeting`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: ah ok, so @Aprillion  LoginButton is called after because of following as {button}
return (
      <div>
        <Greeting isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} />
        {button}
      </div>
    );

Comment: Not @Aprillion, but would say yes, that's the reason :)

Comment: Actually My questions should hav been general and not specific to someone, I hv learnt this today, Thank you for your reply tho, Appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

[JSX provides syntactic sugar](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) for:

```
button = React.createElement(LoginButton, {onClick: this.handleLoginClick})
```

While that code executes before `<Greetings>`, it is not the same as `button = LoginButton()` which would execute the code inside `LoginButton`.

The code inside `LoginButton` is executed only when actually rendered, i.e. in `{button}` inside the component rendered by calling `ReactDOM.render()`.

---

`props` is the value passed as the 2nd argument to `React.createElement` above, and will be passed as the 1st argument to the component implementation.

If you imagine `<LoginButton something="test" />`, then following implementation would display `test` inside the button:

```
const LoginButton = (props) => <button>{props.something}</button>
```

However, `onClick` specifically is a prop recognized by build-in React elements like `<button>` or `<div>` that will wait for a user to click on that element and call the function specified by developer on each click - see [Handling events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) for more.